# Removing attributes and refresh element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have divs on my page containing content I want to keep hidden until another element is clicked.

When hiding them I had 3 options:

**visibilty: hidden** - Didn't like this as the div with content was still taking up space in my layout

**display: none** - This worked but the content was now not available to search engines.

**Positioned, Clipped, and (almost) Collapsed** - I found this method with a google search and it has the following:

```
.element-invisible {
  position: absolute !important;
  height: 1px; width: 1px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
```

This seems to work for what I want and keeps the content searchable.

Now I want to show that content when a user clicks another element.

I thought I could use .removeAttr() and this would remove all those that are set and show my content, and then set them back in with attr().

Well I didn't get very far as .removeAttr() didn't seem to show the div. Nothing happened really, lol.

Is my thinking all wrong here?

Comment: What attribute are you removing with `removeAttr`? I think you have to add the javascript code are you using... Anyway I think that if you are assigning those CSS to a class like you show us above, you could use removeClass instead...

Comment: You should simply remove the _class_ from the element, that is used to apply this formatting in the first place - and not try and remove individual CSS properties one by one ...

Comment: Ah yes, silly me - remove the class. As you can tell I am a newb at this stuff so lot's of learning going on.

Answer (score 0):

As the latest Bootstrap suggests, you may use this as an example:

```
.element-invisible {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```